# $M_B(\phi)$ is an upper triangular matrix iff $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$ and $U_i$ is $\phi$-invariant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-subspace

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field, $1\leq n\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $V$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space with $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}V=n$.

Let $\phi :V\rightarrow V$ be a linear map.

I want to show that the following two statements are equivalent:

- There is a basis $B$ of $V$ such that $M_B(\phi)$ is an upper triangular matrix.
- There are subspaces $U_1, \ldots , U_n\leq_{\mathbb{K}}V$ such that $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$ and $U_i$ is $\phi$-invariant.

Could you give me a hint for that?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\mathcal B = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $M_{\mathcal B}(\phi)$ is upper-triangular, then the subspaces $U_i = \operatorname{span}\{v_1,\dots,v_i\}$ are invariant subspace of $\phi$.

Comment: How does this follow? I got stuck right now.

Comment: @MaryStar Another hint: show that if $M_{\mathcal B}$ is upper triangular, then we can write 
$$
\phi(v_i) = c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_i v_i
$$
for some coefficients $c_1,\dots,c_i$. Can you see why this implies that $U_i$ is $\phi$-invariant? Try to show this inductively: why is $U_1$ invariant? If $U_1$ is invariant, then how do we see that $U_2$ is invariant? And so forth.

Comment: Ahh we have that $v_i\in U_i$ and that $\phi (v_i)\in U_i$ and this means that $U_i$ is $\phi$-invariant, right?

Comment: @MaryStar well it's clear that $\phi(v_i) \in U_i$, but it's important that we use some of the context to show that $U_i$ is invariant. In particular, we can show that $U_i$ is invariant by noting that $\phi(v_j) \in U_i$ for all $j \leq i$, since the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_i$ form a basis of $U_i$.

Comment: Ah so to show that $U_i$ is $\phi$-invariant do we have to show that $\phi (v_j)\in U_i$ for all $j\leq i$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Right. However, if we proceed inductively then this comes "for free" because $\phi(v_j) \in U_j \subset U_i$.

Comment: Ok, so for that we have to show the first part, that $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$, or not?

Comment: @Mary Yes. That should be pretty quick to show, though

Comment: Do we have that $u_1, \ldots , u_i\in U_i$ and $u_1, \ldots , u_i, u_{i+1}\in U_{i+1}$ and so $U_i\subseteq U_{i+1}$ and since $u_{i+1}\notin U_i$ it follows that $U_i\subset U_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: Or is this proof incorrect or not complete?

Comment: @MaryStar That's correct and complete

Comment: For the other direction I did the following: \begin{align*}&\phi (u_1) + \cdots +  \phi (u_{i-1})=\tilde{c}_{(i-1)1}u_1+\ldots +\tilde{c}_{(i-1)(i-1)}u_{i-1} \ \ \ \ (\star) \\ & \phi (u_1) + \cdots + \phi (u_{i-1})+  \phi (u_i)=\tilde{c}_{i1}u_1+\ldots +\tilde{c}_{i(i-1)}u_{i-1}+\tilde{c}_{ii}u_i \ \ \ \ (\star\star)\end{align*} 
We calculate $(\star\star)-(\star)$ and get \begin{equation*}\phi (u_i)=\lambda_1u_1+\ldots +\lambda_{i-1}u_{i-1}+\lambda_iu_i\end{equation*} 
This means that $M_{\mathcal{B}}(\phi)$ is an upper-triangular matrix. Is this proof correct?